# Canonical updated with JS - is this used by SEO?

Tags: javascript, dom, seo, search-engine, canonical-link

Due to some hindrance by BigCommerce, I have to update my products' canonical links using Javascript. This is because BigCommerce auto-generates canonical URLs and I had to modify a template file that affects each product.

I was able to replace the URL by using Javascript to find the canonical in the DOM and replacing the `href` appropriately. My code works however, I only notice these changes in the DOM when inspecting the head of the page. Viewing the source shows the original canonical still there.

After running my page through a Canonical URL Checker (http://www.seoreviewtools.com/canonical-url-location-checker/), it displays the original source link instead of my modified one. Will search engines process my new canonicals? Is there another way around this?

Comment: Why don't you use regular canonical urls instead of a hack?

Comment: @JohnConde I cannot manually insert canonicals. It's a default part of the template that is auto-generated and placed by BigCommerce. Because of this I had to write my own script that's inserted in the template to modify what's already there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first I must say, this seems to be a bad workaround.
And yet, at least in the case of google, it should work.
you can see section 4 in this [article](http://searchengineland.com/tested-googlebot-crawls-javascript-heres-learned-220157)